# Changing the date when a certain word is used

Tags: excel, vba, date

Hoping someone can help. I have a excel sheet where column x has a drop down option of listing "Open" or "Closed." Whenever a new row is added, I need to mark it as open but eventually once the project is finished, I need to mark it as "Closed" using the drop down in column x. I have another column, D, that lists the closed date. Is it possible to have the date automatically populate in column d when column x is marked as "Closed"? I've found codes that will populate a date when a value is entered in the cell but none where the date is populated when the value is changed.

Comment: Yes it is possible. You could research the `Worksheet.Change` event.

Answer (score 0):

yes, by using the below formula to get close date automatically

=IF(X10="Closed",TODAY(),"")

but the problem is if the formula remains in closed column then the date will change automatically in next day, so once closed then u should remove the formula